# Static Header Bar is behind my contents

Tags: html, css

I created a static bar with the code:

```
#header_bar {
    background-image: url(../img/background_white.png);
    height: 64px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

And my code for my content:

```
#content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #D8F0DA;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;

    background-image: url(../img/wallpaper.jpg); 
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

It worked and my header bar became static but when I scroll down the header bar stays behind my contents. How can I fix this?

Comment: Either place the header later in the html (later elements are naturally considered to be "in front" of earlier elements) or use a `z-index` style to force the header on top of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add a `z-index` to the header bar's CSS class:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
```

Should make it appear on top of content.