# stop content going over the top of paper-dialog-scrollable - Polymer

Tags: html, css, polymer

I have a paper-dialog-scrollable as my main section for content. However, if I have anything other than text within the dialog, when scrolling, the subtle shadow that is produced on the dialog header is underneath the content.

**Text only - With shadow separator**

[image: Text only - With shadow separator]

**Div only - Without shadow separator**

[image: Div only - Without shadow separator]

Is there any way to correct this? I am thinking maybe it is a z-index issue?

```
<div class="contentSection" style="width:100%">
    <paper-tabs selected="0" noink>
         <paper-tab link>
              <a href="#item1" tabindex="-1">TAB 1</a>
          </paper-tab>
          <paper-tab link>
               <a href="#item2" tabindex="-1">TAB 2</a>
          </paper-tab>
          <paper-tab link>
               <a href="#item3" tabindex="-1">TAB 3</a>
           </paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>

        <paper-dialog-scrollable>
            <sample-content size="10"></sample-content>
         </paper-dialog-scrollable>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please include your code - HTML and CSS, and ideally set up a demo replicating the issue. You will get a lot more help with your question

Comment: Sorry! Totally spaced on that one! Edited now

Comment: The answer indeed lies within the z-index as found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797865/3061047)